# Can I override subscript in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, overriding, subscript

I want to do validity check and return appropriate value in array in swift, like below function objectFromArr(at:).

```
var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40]

func objectFromArr(at: Int) -> Int? {
    return at < 0 || at >= arr.count ? nil : arr[at]
}
```

I don't want to use function. Because of swift Array typically uses subscript to get object.
So, I want to override subscript if possible.

```
@inlinable public subscript(index: Int) -> Element

to

override @inlinable public subscript(index: Int) -> Element?
```

Comment: This is actually a broader different question than the duplicate, even though the example itself is addressed by the duplicate.

Comment: Well the question is adequately answered so there seems little purpose in reopening it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override the existing subscript, for two reasons:

1. Structs don't support inheritance and method overrides, period
2. Even if they did, this would break existing code, which wouldn't expect the result to be optional.

Instead, just define a new extension:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safelyAccess index: Index) -> Element? {
        get { return self.indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil }
    }
}

let a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a[safelyAccess: 99]) // => nil
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you Alexander. I didn't know that can use parameter name to subscript parameter.

Comment: Great! and you can apply it in a class like
`
    class MyClass: NSObject, Sequence {
     private var _array: [DisplayedEntry] = []

     subscript(index: Int) -> DisplayedEntry? {
        get { return self._etfEntries.indices.contains(index) ? self._etfEntries[index] : nil }
    }}

`